# How to implement Spring Boot service classes without using impl and using a interface as dependency as DIP principle says?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I am trying to implement a Spring Boot REST API but I was asked to use a interface as dependency but no impl, and I don't know how to achieve this. The way I implemented was to have service classes for my entities and there I would just call the repository in my methods. I would like an example of implementation like this.

I watched some youtube tutorials but they all used impl classes

Comment: An interface always needs an implementation else it doesn't do anything. However your users (like the controller) should use the interface and not the implementation class.

Comment: @M.Deinum I still don't understand how I could do this for a service class, basically when I instantiate my service class in the controller, I should use something like InterfaceForService = new ImplementationForService ? And I should say that my ImplementationForService implements InterfaceForService? Right now this is the single way it makes sense for me

Comment: You don't instantiate it in the controller, you should inject it by interface.

Comment: can you offer an example, please?

Comment: Those examples are all over the Spring (Boot) documentation already, not sure what we need in addition to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller should have a field of your interface type, with the injecting annotation (in spring it's `@Autowired`). The DI framework will do the heavy-lifting on startup and inject the correct implementation at runtime

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired    
    private MyInterface myInterface;
    ....
}
```

For this to work, your framework needs to recognize the concrete class. In spring you can achieve this in multiple ways - scanning package paths, xml configuration files and more.

Check the spring documentation to see which way suits you best

Comment: It is necessary that this interface to have a Configuration annotation ? Or is it enough to have Bean? And should I do an interface for each service class or is it enough to have a global one that has all the methods needed I thought a little about it but it doesn't seem very correct to have a interface for all the service classes, as it will get huge for a big project

Comment: @Leobej1 The correct way to do DI is to have ALL injected beans go through an interface. You never know when you'll need to replace an implementation or have multiple impls, that's exactly why you use this pattern. When you use concrete classes, you create couplings and therefore dependencies in your code.

Comment: Annotations are one way to achieve this, you can also use pure-xml configurations. That's up to you, but my preferred way is annotations

Comment: Thank you for your response and patience, I am very grateful.